# saveGIF in R works seems to work for plot but not ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, animation, ggplot2

I am trying to use saveGIF function in the animation package in R. No problem with plot but get an error with ggplot

As shown below, toy plotting functions work with plot but error thrown with ggplot

```
simplePlot <- function (){

df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                            len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p

df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                 len=c(5.2, 5, 19.5))
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p

}

simplerPlot <- function(){
  df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                   len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
  plot(df)
  df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                   len=c(5.2, 5, 19.5))
  plot(df)

}
```

---> works

```
saveGIF(simplerPlot(),movie.name = 'test.gif')
```

---> throws error

```
saveGIF(simplePlot(),movie.name = 'test.gif')
```

This is the error thrown by saveGIF(simplePlot(),movie.name = 'test.gif')

```
Error in if (100%%fps) stop("argument 'fps' must be a factor of 100") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Does not happen with saveGIF(simplerPlot(),movie.name = 'test.gif')

Comment: you probably need `print(plot(df))`  ... this may a variation of https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f

Comment: print(p) with ggplot version in simplePlot?

Comment: That worked! Thank you.